# Is there a way to use INSTR() function in DERBY DATABASE?

Tags: sql, derby

Is there any way to use `INSTR('asd','a',1)` (which we have for oracle) in Derby databse?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LOCATE for this purpose.

https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefsqlj61998.html

> The LOCATE function is used to search for a string within another
>   string. If the desired string is found, LOCATE returns the index at
>   which it is found. If the desired string is not found, LOCATE returns
>   0.

Syntax

```
LOCATE(CharacterExpression, CharacterExpression [, StartPosition] )
```